# Ajax Form Validation Messages don't show

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

This is for the first time I'm working on validations in Asp.Net MVC-4.

> The problem here is that the validation messages don't show for the
>   required fields even when I post an empty form.

This is the form I'm using:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save","DSA",
    new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.DSAId)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.DSAId)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Firstname)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Firstname)

<input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

And in the Model Class:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "DSA ID is required")]
    public string DSAId { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
```

And this is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Save(Models.clsDSAMaster MyModel,string submit)
  {
      string data = "";

      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          MyModel.Insert_DSA.addDSA(MyModel.Insert_DSA, Session["EmpCode"].ToString());
          data="success"; 

      }
     else
     {
         data="Faliure";
     }


     return Content(data, "text/html");
  }
```

Can anyone please help me get it to work and enlighten me a little on how validations work in MVC.

**P.S :** The model binding and the data retrieval from the model on the form submit is working perfectly.

Comment: Have you included the relevant scripts? (`jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`). And your `Ajax.BeginForm()` does not specify a target element to update so `return Content(data, "text/html");` wont do anything

Comment: Yeah i've added the JS files

Comment: @StephenMuecke so how to specify the target element

Comment: If you have added the files correctly, the form will not submit if its invalid. You need to add the `UpdateTargetId` AjaxOption and specify the id of an element where you want the data to be displayed - but that will only display "success" or "Faliure" (sic), because that's all your method returns

Comment: @StephenMuecke "the form will not submit if its invalid" that's exactly what I want and with this the validation messages should be displayed for the corresponding elements.Will that happen too?

Comment: If you have included the script correctly (and have not disabled client side validation), then that's exactly what will happen - the messages will be displayed and the form will not submit until corrected

Comment: @StephenMuecke <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> this is the only file I had and I've included it in the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke how and where do I get the necessary files needed for validation, could you just give me an Idea please?

Comment: That file is for the ajax form only. You need to include `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` (after `jquery{version}.js`) - which is typically done using `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` but you can add them individually

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke ! you have been a great deal of help to me and to every one else here. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable unobtrusive JavaScript. You can do it in the configuration file:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

or you can also turn it on form the code:

```
HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
```